# C# Find Directories Without System and Hidden Folder

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

I want to get all directories in a list without system and hidden flagged folders on a drive.

Example:

```
var Dizinler = Directory.EnumerateDirectories("C:\")
               .Select(s => new DirectoryInfo(s))
               .Where(s => !s.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory | FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.Hidden) )
               .Select(s=> s.FullName).ToArray();
```

However, the returned results still contains hidden and system folders.

Comment: `!s.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory | FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.Hidden)` means "not directory and system and hidden attributes **combined**"; so if directory is, say, hidden but not system it passes the filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, you should not combine all attributes:

```
var Dizinler = Directory.EnumerateDirectories("C:\")
           .Select(s => new DirectoryInfo(s))
           .Where(s => s.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory))
           .Where(s => !s.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System))
           .Where(s => !s.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
           .Select(s=> s.FullName).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `|`. Do it like:

```
    var Dizinler = Directory.EnumerateDirectories("C:\")
.Select(s => new DirectoryInfo(s)).Where(s => s.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory) &&
    !s.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System) && !s.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden) )
.Select(s=> s.FullName).ToArray();
```